# Saving worksheet using file path + cell data = error 424

Tags: excel, vba

I have been stuck on an issue for over a day.

Basically I have written a loop macro that takes a list of numbers from a worksheet called [FILES], inputs this into a a single cell table [Table9] this is the product number, changing the number in [Table9] then triggers macros that refresh some linked tables, and deletes the working sheets saving only the results as product number and label. H:\Files\011140 Product Financial Allocation.xlsx

This is the loop, i'm getting "424 object required" error

```
Sub LOOPING()

Dim FilePath As String
FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Range("Table9[ProgramID]") & " Product Financial Allocation" & ".xlsx"

For i = 3 To 6

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Sheets("FILES").Range("A" & i).Copy Sheets("TEMPLATE").Range("Table9[ProgramID]")

    Workbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=FilePath

  Next i

End Sub
```

I have also tried not defining the file path and directly stating the path in the save copyline

```
Workbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=Thisworkbook.Path & Range("Table9[ProgramID]") & " Product Financial Allocation" & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

Any help would be appreciated

If you need the next step of the Macro then its

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Target.Address = Range("Table9[ProgramID]").Address Then

Call FilterTOGGLE
Call RefreshA
Call RefreshB
Call RefreshC
Call RefreshD
Call CurrencyFormat
Call FilterTOGGLE
Call FilterYears
Call DELETE

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What's `Workbook`? Did you mean `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: I change it to thisworkbook but that doesnt work either

Comment: If you are trying to refer to `ThisWorkbook` change _all_  your implicit `Active*` references

Comment: `FilePath` never changes so you're overwriting each successive time you save.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean as I dont have any active references, I thought that might be a bad idea given the loop is running off the main sheet and changing to active cell would throw out the loop.

Bigben sorry what are you saying? the path is just 'h:\test' so pretty easy for me to just replace file path with that, but still doesn't work